# NHibernate SqlException "Value cannot be null"

Tags: c#, nhibernate

When I'm trying to save an object, it threw ADOException "Could not save object". Resulted SqlCommand is null. Under it, there's another exception caught by internal process;"Value cannot be null". I looked up a bit, it should tell which parameter that is null, but in my case it doesn't.

This is the whole exception message

```
Exception:Thrown: "Value cannot be null." (System.ArgumentNullException)
```

A System.ArgumentNullException was thrown: "Value cannot be null."
Time: 19/6/2556 16:14:25
Thread:[6380]

I'm 100% certain that object I'm trying to save doesn't contain any null variables. Though, there's a variable(alarm_id) that was changed from what I put in to null. I make the variable non-null value, and it turned to 0 instead.

Anyone knows what's wrong?

Here's the method

```
public bool Save<T>(SessionAction sessionAction, T item)
{
    bool success = true;
    if ((sessionAction == SessionAction.Begin) || (sessionAction == SessionAction.BeginAndEnd))
    {
        _isRollback = false;
        Session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession();
        _transaction = Session.BeginTransaction();
    }

    try
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            success = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Session.Save(item);

            //Session.Flush();
            //Session.Evict(item);
            if ((sessionAction == SessionAction.End) || (sessionAction == SessionAction.BeginAndEnd))
            {
                _transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (ADOException e)
    {
        NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlString s = e.SqlString;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        errMsg = ex.Message;
        success = false;
        try
        {
            _isRollback = true;
            _transaction.Rollback();
        }
        catch { }
    }

    if ((sessionAction == SessionAction.End) || (sessionAction == SessionAction.BeginAndEnd))
    {
        if (Session != null) Session.Close();
        Session = null;
        _transaction = null;
        _connection = null;
    }

    return success;
}
```

Object's hbm

```
<hibernate-mapping assembly="ServicesLib" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"><class name="ServicesLib.Entities.alarm_raw_data, ServicesLib" table="alarm_raw_data" lazy="true" >
<id name="alarm_id" column="alarm_id">
  <generator class="identity" />
</id>
<!--property name="alarm_timestamp" column="alarm_timestamp"/-->
<property name="dcs_source" column="dcs_source" />
<property name="event_type" column="event_type" />
<property name="parameter" column="parameter" />
<property name="tag_desc" column="tag_desc" />
<property name="tag_name" column="tag_name" not-null="true"/>
```

And here's the input I send in.

```
data.tag_name = inf.content[0];

data.alarm_id = 3;
data.dcs_source = 44;
data.event_type = 56;
data.parameter = 5555;
data.tag_desc = 'd';

connector.Save(SessionAction.BeginAndEnd, data);
```

Comment: Its an ADOException which means it's thrown from the database, have a look at the generated SQL.

Comment: I tried, but the only way to know the sql command is through the exception, which the value is null.

Comment: You don't have SQL Profiler or NHProf?

Comment: alarm_timestamp is commented out, is it null or default in your database?

Comment: Phill - no. I'm quite new to database stuff. And DB should fill the timestamp automatically, right?

Comment: If its set to timestamp yes. If you're working with this locally, you should have SQL Profiler. Can go Tools > Profiler, and it will show all commands executed against the db. Really need the SQL to be able to figure out whats wrong.

Comment: I got this from a free profiler. Still have no idea what's wrong.

'exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO alarm_raw_data (dcs_source, event_type, parameter, tag_desc, tag_name) VALUES ({at}p0, {at}p1, {at}p2, {at}p3, {at}p4); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()',N'{at}p0 bigint,{at}p1 bigint,{at}p2 bigint,{at}p3 nchar(1),{at}p4 nchar(1)',{at}p0=44,{at}p1=56,{at}p2=5555,{at}p3=N'd',{at}p4=N'3''

Comment: @Phill Weird enough. When I put that command directly into sql management studio query window, it passed fine.

Comment: Ahh, in the profiler, is there an update after the insert?

Comment: No. There's a "exec sp_reset_connection" comes after, but that should be from closing the connection.

Comment: Could you try removing the assignment of alarm_id and setting the mapping to be `native` instead of identity.

Comment: doesn't help anything. Is it possible that I config something wrong in App.Config in C# project?

Answer (score 0):

Weird, probably unrelated, but since your generator is identity, why are you setting the alarm_id field to 3? leave it unassigned and it will have a value after the object is saved.